# How to nest an <a href=""> when using $(this).clone()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div id="myPost>"` that is populated with the Jquery clone code `$(this).clone().appendTo('#myPost');`.

I want the users to click in this div, so it will take them to another page. How can you do nest an `a href` tag in the clone?

The blue area is the cloned part that should be clickable and take you to another page. The blue area has a `div` called `#myPost`. So I want to add a link to the following page: `#individualProfile`. I dont want to add more code because `div #myPost` gets data from the server via ajax. But I guess my question is how to add an anchor tag inside `#myPost` when it cloned.

Comment: `append` a child a element to the clone

Comment: Can you give us a HTML representation of what the end result would be? Can you show us what  you've tried?

Comment: @PeterKA, I know it seems little code, but I guess what I am looking does not need lots of code. I have #myPost cloned fine from another div called `#myListView`. Then when is cloned, I wan users to click in the div `#myPost` (the cloned one) to link them to another page.

Comment: All we are asking is for you to clarify your requirement; the level of clarity has a direct relationship to the quality of answers you get. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.append('<a href="some.url">')`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ep5k7h74/

Comment: hi @Jamie Barker, Thanks, but as you can see, I have a #myList cloned so I do I append? This is not working : `.appendTo('#myPost' + '<a href="#individualProfile"></a>')`

Comment: You do it in a separate call. see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ep5k7h74/4/

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your HTML makes this tricky, but this should get you started.

```
var clonedDiv = $( this ).clone();
clonedDiv.append( '<a href="yourUrl">Link Title</a>' );
$( this ).appendTo( '#myPost' );
```